# Abstraction in Delphi

Tags: delphi, class

If I have child class,the child class inherits all methods from the parent,but how do I use functions from the child class in the parent class? Is that what abstraction is? How do I accomplish it?

My code:

```
type
cParent = class(TObject)
private
  function ParentFunction:byte;
  function ChildFunction:byte;virtual;abstract;
end;

type
cChild = class(cParent)
private function ChildFunction:byte;override;
end;

function cChild.ChildFunction:byte;
begin
  Exit(20);
end;

function cParent.ParentFunction:byte;
begin
  Exit(10);
end;

var
c:cParent;

begin
  c:= cParent.Create;
  WriteLn(c.ChildFunction);
  Readln;
end.
```

It compiles file,but I get abstraction exception.

Comment: When you say it compiles fine, do you really mean that you did *not* get a warning from the compiler telling you that you were instantiating an abstract class? You need to be more diligent about stamping out compiler hints and warnings, not just errors.

Comment: Just a few comments regarding conventional style. 
It is usual in Delphi to prefix class (and other type) names with T, not c.
The return value of functions is usually set by setting the implicit Result variable to a value, rather than using Exit i.e. Result := 10;, not Exit(10);. The Exit syntax was only added in D2009
Note: You can also use the function name, rather than result (ParentFunction := 10;) - the effect is the same and it is the original Pascal syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c:= cParent.Create;
WriteLn(c.ChildFunction);
```

You create an instance of cParent class here. This class does only contain an abstract ChildFunction that can be overridden by other classes. The function is not implemented in cParent, so you get an abstract error.

The code works if you use the cChild class instead, where ChildFunction is implemented:

```
c:= cChild.Create;
WriteLn(c.ChildFunction);
```

For clarification, imagine a parent class named `GeometricObject` with an virtual abstract method `CalculateVolume`. You can now create child classes like `SphereObject` or `BoxObject` that implement `CalculateVolume` by using the formula for spheres/boxes. But it doesn't make sense to create an instance of `GeometricObject` and call `CalculateVolume`.

Comment: Ok ,but then what is the use of "virtual","abstract" and "override" keyword?

Comment: "virtual" means the method can be overridden by child classes. "abstract" means the method isn't implemented by the parent class, but can be implemented in child classes. "override", well, overrides virtual methods from parent classes. All abstract methods must be virtual, but methods can be virtual without being abstract.

Comment: abstract methods are what C++ refers to as "pure virtual" methods. They must be implemented in a child class.

Answer (score 2):

You create instance of cParent class. This class don't have implementation of childFunction. c must be instance of cChild class.
Correct code:
c := cChild.Create;
WriteLn(c.ChildFunction);

Answer (score 1):

Create the instance using the child class:

```
c:= cChild.Create;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have confused inheritance relationships and possessive relationships. If you define a class "cChild" as inherited from class "cParent" then the class "cChild" **is** a "cParent", it does not mean, that the class "Parent" has access to any child classes. The only way you can call the abstract function "ChildFunction" in the class "cParent" is from another function, e.g. "ParentFunction", but only if the Object itself is not a "cParent":

```
function cParent.ParentFunction:byte;
begin
  Result := ChildFunction * 2;
end;

var
  c:cParent;

begin
  c:= cChild.Create;
  WriteLn(c.ParentFunction);
  Readln;
end.
```

Here, since c is a cChild, ParentFunction correctly calls ChildFunction, which is defined in cChild.

Answer (score 0):

In response to schnaader, regarding CS 101:

> "virtual" means the method can be overridden by child classes.

Not only this, but non-virtual functions may happily be overridden by child classes.  The difference is very important: when a virtual function is called by the parent class, the CHILD function will be executed.  This allows child classes to implement functions that will be called by parent classes without the parent ever knowing anything about them.  This is the essence of **polymorphism**.